# WebSocket can't see Typescript class properties in event handler methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

**Situation**

I have following typescript files:

*PlayerList.ts*

*GameEngineInterface.ts*

```
interface GameEngineInterface {
  onNewPlayer(socket: Socket):void
}
```

*GameEngine.ts*

```
class GameEngine implements GameEngineInterface {
  constructor(private playerList: PlayerList = new PlayerList()){}
  onNewPlayer(socket: Socket) {
    playerList.addPlayer(socket)
  }
}
```

*index.ts*

```
const gameEngine: GameEngineInterface = new GameEngine();
const httpServer = new Http.Server({}).listen(3000);
const websocketApp = new SocketIO(httpServer);

websocketApp.on("connection", gameEngine.onNewPlayerConnect);
```

When browser connects to this websocket server, this error is thrown

> var player = this.playerList.addPlayer(socket);
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPlayer' of undefined

If I change the last line in *index.ts* to

`websocketApp.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => gameEngine.onNewPlayerConnect(socket));`

then the error disappears.

**Question**

1. What went wrong with my code in the first place?
2. Why the fix worked?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `this` in an event handler function is normally bound to the event source. When you call the function with dot notation (instead of the event queue calling it directly) you're binding a different `this` to the function.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. I didn't know event handlers work like that. I think using arrow function doesn't look neat. Do you have a suggestion on how to do bindings directly in the GameEngine.ts file itself so I don't have to use arrow function in index.ts?

Comment: That arrow function is OK as it is. You can also use `bind` to bind `this` to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you pass function
`websocketApp.on("connection", gameEngine.onNewPlayerConnect);`
way the binding of the `onNewPlayerConnect` is to websocketApp, there fore the `this` context is point to it
in arrow function  the binding `onNewPlayerConnect` is retained